# Issue trying to import pyaudio to pycharm

Tags: python, pip, pycharm, pyaudio

Whenever i try to import any type of addon for Pycharm i receive an error, i tried many methods to fix this, like:

1.) Updating pip

2.) Editing the PATH

3.) Making sure there's one version of python (python 3) that is fully updated and integrated with Pycharm

4.) downloading windows visual code

5.) Made sure interpreter was synced

Here's the error for a more visual representation:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\temne\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\temne\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-yljd37i3\\pyaudio\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\temne\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-yljd37i3\\pyaudio\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\temne\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-nllhhklr\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\temne\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\Include\pyaudio'
         cwd: C:\Users\temne\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-yljd37i3\pyaudio\
    Complete output (15 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8
    copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8
    running build_ext
    building '_portaudio' extension
    creating build\temp.win32-3.8
    creating build\temp.win32-3.8\Release
    creating build\temp.win32-3.8\Release\src
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Ic:\users\temne\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\include -Ic:\users\temne\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /Tcsrc/_portaudiomodule.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.8\Release\src/_portaudiomodule.obj
    _portaudiomodule.c
    src/_portaudiomodule.c(29): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'portaudio.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.26.28801\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\temne\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\temne\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-yljd37i3\\pyaudio\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\temne\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-yljd37i3\\pyaudio\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\temne\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-nllhhklr\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\temne\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\Include\pyaudio' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Is there something i'm still missing or didn't configure? I'm still currently working on it and some insight will be much appreciated

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpyaudio%5D+fatal+error+C1083%3A+Cannot+open+include+file+portaudio.h+No+such+file+or+directory

Answer (score -1):

if you want to import packages in PyCharm then you can just go through:
Settings/Preferences -> Project -> Project Interpreter and then click the "+" at the bottom and then search whichever package you want.

But if you want Plugins then go through:
Settings/Preferences -> Plugins

I just checked the packages and pyaudio is available there.

Comment: I also get an error trying to do that